# Convert.ToInt64 fails when value is "0.00000"

Tags: c#

5   my code is like this

```
protected long Getvalue()
{
   DataTable dt = GetDataBaseValue();
     if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
     {
      return Convert.ToInt64(dt.Rows[0]["BALANCE"].ToString());
     }
    return 0;
}
```

`dt.Rows[0]["BALANCE"].ToString()=0.00000` I am getting the error here

PS: I tried to do this `return long.Parse(...)` and I got the same error

Comment: Could you not do (long)double.Parse(...)? This will first parse the string to a double, then truncate the value to an integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that "0.00000" is a *String*, which is an *invalid format* for ["parsing to a long"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b6b4bx3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)<sup>1</sup>.

However, it may be sufficient to *omit* the `ToString()` conversion, and thus the above error, depending on what type the database actually returns. If the database returns an appropriate double/float/decimal then the following "Will Work", even if losing precision.

```
// Source is a double
Convert.ToInt64(0.0d)             // -> 0
Convert.ToInt64(0.5d)             // -> 0 (half-even rounding)
Convert.ToInt64(1.5d)             // -> 2 (half-even rounding)
Convert.ToInt64(double.MaxValue)  // -> OverflowException

// Source is a string
Convert.ToInt64("0")    // -> 0
Convert.ToInt64("0.0")  // -> FormatException: "not in a correct format"
```

If, for some uncorrectable reason, the database returns a String in the given format, it should suffice to first convert the string to a double/decimal (which do support such a format) and *then* to a long. Similar overflow and loss of precision cases are possible.

```
long v = (long)Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[0]["BALANCE"]);
```

---

By default, .NET will parse integer values (e.g. int, long) from strings *only* when they conform to the pattern `\s*[-+]?\d+\s*` and will throw a FormatException otherwise; this is discussed in more detail in the linked documentation.

Answer (score 6):

`0.00000` is not a valid value for `Int64`. Perhaps you intended to use a `Decimal` (it looks like a currency amount) or otherwise truncate/round the value first?

Comment: i want to convert this value to long and not to decimal

Comment: @Sora then don't convert it to a string first.

Comment: @Sora So what if the value were '-27.14369'? What would you want it to convert to?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Decimal.Parse("0.0000");` this is used for currency Not Long or Int64